# Custom WooCommerce Gateway - Running Local JS Function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

## Overview

### Core Problem

I'm a little lost on how I can get the WooCommerce Order payload data into a pre-loaded JS function (`pru_checkout()`)

### Explanation

I'm building an extension for "Payments-R-Us."  PRU has given me a JS snippet that is loaded onto the **Checkout page**.  When the **Checkout Button** is pressed, I need to fire off the `pru_checkout()` function (with the appropriate JSON payload).  Then, a modal box will pop up to guide them through the checkout process (the modal + all of its data points are 100% coded and functioning with the JS snippet they have provided) to complete the purchase.  When all the steps are complete, the JS snippet will hit a custom endpoint I will create within WC to trigger the **Order Status change** + the redirection to the Thank You page.

---

## What I've Tried

### Process Payment Function

Inside my Gateway class, there is the core `process_payment( $order_id )` function.  This hasn't worked due to the lack being able to send data to a JS function already loaded onto the page.

### Callback Handler

This is more for "step 2" of the process, but I did look into how to implement a callback handler, but everything is done "behind the scenes" while I need to access the local JS function directly on the **Checkout Page** when the button is pressed - not to pass data after the fact (http://dominykasgel.com/woocommerce-creating-callback-url/)

### Custom JS

I was considering writing some custom JS that hooked on the button press of the **Checkout Button**, but that doesn't give me access to the *Order Object* or any of the user details I need to pass into the payload.

---

## Code Samples

### Gateway Class

```php
/**
 * Initialize the PRU Gateway class
 */
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'pru_initialize_gateway_class' );
function pru_initialize_gateway_class() {

    class WC_PaymentsRUs_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        /**
         * Class constructor
         */
        public function __construct() {

            // Set variables that WooCommerce is expecting from any payment gateway
            $this->id                 = 'pru_gateway'; // Unique ID
            $this->icon               = 'image.jpg'; // PaymentsRUs logo
            $this->has_fields         = false; // FALSE hides the credit card fields
            $this->method_title       = 'PaymentsRUs'; // Title shown on admin screen
            $this->method_description = 'Allow checkout with PaymentsRUs modal box.  <strong>NOTE:</strong> This extension requires a newer version of jQuery than what WordPress is packaged with by default.'; // Description shown on admin screen


            // Support payments for PRODUCTS only
            $this->supports = array(
                'products'
            );

            // Initialize form fields
            $this->init_form_fields();

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_settings();
            $this->dealer                = $this->get_option( 'dealer' );
            $this->base_plan             = $this->get_option( 'base_plan' );
            $this->program               = $this->get_option( 'program' );
            $this->promo                 = $this->get_option( 'promo' );
            $this->channel               = $this->get_option( 'channel' );
            $this->api_key               = $this->get_option( 'api_key' );
            $this->sandbox               = $this->get_option( 'sandbox' );
            $this->toggle_single_product = $this->get_option( 'toggle_single_product' );
            $this->debug_mode            = $this->get_option( 'debug_mode' );
            $this->toggle_product_pods   = $this->get_option( 'toggle_product_pods' );
            $this->toggle_cart           = $this->get_option( 'toggle_cart' );


            // This action hook saves the settings
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array(
                $this,
                'process_admin_options'
            ) );


            // Bind the API callback URL
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_bobrocks', array($this,'callback_handler') );


        }

        /**
         * Form field setup for Settings page
         */
        public function init_form_fields() {

            $this->form_fields = array(


                'api_key' => array(
                    'title'       => 'API Key',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => 'This is some sample description text that can be changed',
                    //'default'     => 'Credit Card',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),

                'dealer' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Dealer ID',
                    'type'        => 'number',
                    'description' => 'This is some sample description text that can be changed',
                    //'default'     => 'Credit Card',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),

                'base_plan' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Base Plan',
                    'type'        => 'number',
                    'description' => 'This is some sample description text that can be changed',
                    //'default'     => 'Credit Card',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),

                'promo' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Promo Code',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => 'This is some sample description text that can be changed',
                    //'default'     => 'Credit Card',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),

                'program' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Program',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => 'This is some sample description text that can be changed',
                    //'default'     => 'Credit Card',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),

                'channel' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Channel',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => 'This is some sample description text that can be changed',
                    //'default'     => 'Credit Card',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),

                'sandbox' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Sandbox Mode',
                    'label'       => 'Check to enable Sandbox mode',
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => '',
                    'default'     => 'no'
                ),

                'debug_mode' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Debug Mode',
                    'label'       => 'Check to turn debug mode ON in the console',
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => '',
                    'default'     => 'no'
                ),

                'toggle_single_product' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Show ALA on Single Product',
                    'label'       => 'Checking this box will show the ALA on a Single Product',
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => '',
                    'default'     => 'yes'
                ),

                'toggle_product_pods' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Show ALA on Product Pod',
                    'label'       => 'Checking this box will show the ALA on a Product Pod (ie. the Shop page)',
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => '',
                    'default'     => 'yes'
                ),

                'toggle_cart' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Show ALA on Cart',
                    'label'       => 'Checking this box will show the ALA on the Cart page',
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => '',
                    'default'     => 'yes'
                ),


            );

        }

        /**
         * Credit card fields
         */
        public function payment_fields() {

            //

        }

        /*
         * Custom CSS and JS
         */
        public function payment_scripts() {

            //

        }

        /*
         * Fields validation
         */
        public function validate_fields() {

            //

        }

        /*
         * We're processing the payments here
         */
        public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

            global $woocommerce;
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            print_r($order);

        }

        /*
         * Webhooks
         */
        public function webhook() {

            //

        }




        public function callback_handler() {
            $a = array(
                'bob',
                'rocks'
            );

            echo json_encode($a);
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

### JSON Payload for JS Function

```
{
    "applicant": {
        "firstName": "BOB",
        "lastname": DOE",
        "streetaddress": "1234 N BROAD AVE ",
        "otheraddress": "Suite 1145",
        "city": "Savannah",
        "state": "GA",
        "zip": "12345",
        "country": "US",
        "phone": "123-456-7890",
        "email": "john@doe.com"
    },
    "shipping": {
        "streetaddress": "1234 N BROAD AVE ",
        "otheraddress": "Suite 1145",
        "city": "Savannah",
        "state": "GA",
        "zip": "12345",
        "country": "US",
    },
    "merchant": {
        "callbackurl": "custom/woocommerce/api/callback",
        "merchantId": "421111154",
        "planNumber": "59422348",
        "promoCode": "Empire012324123123"
    },
    "order": {
        "orderId": "104983763522",
        "totalAmount": 1005
    }
}
```

---

Let me know if I can provide any more detail!

Answer (score 2):

You can use hash, instead of return the order confirmation URL, you can return a hash. Then in the JS side, you listen to `hashchange` to open your modal.

```
return array(
    'result'   => 'success',
    'redirect' => '#some-thing-here',
);
```

We haven’t finished yet, you then need to tell WC to complete your order, empty the cart, and record the payment, you can do this by using WC_Ajax. How? After the customer completes payment in the checkout process in the modal, you redirect the browser to the URL of WC_Ajax action you’ve just registered. How to pass that ajax URL to your JS handler, modify the hash above like this:

```
return array(
    'result'   => 'success',
    'redirect' => '#some-thing-here:ajax-url-here',
);
```

Finally, then you can complete the order, empty cart, redirect to the thank you page in your WC_Ajax handler.

Ps: I've implemented [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) gateway using this flow.

Ps2: This is the way WooCommerce Stripe Gateway handles 3D Secure payment

Comment: can you explain it a bit more in details like where to place this return #url process_payment function. Because I tried to put return array(
    'result'   => 'success',
    'redirect' => '#some-thing-here',
);

but it didn't work but went into infinite loop on checkout page by blocking the whole page!
please elaborate on this a little. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``` lang-js
jQuery(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        var currentHash = location.hash;
        currentHash = currentHash.replace('#', '');
        console.log(`The current URL hash is ${currentHash}`);
        if(currentHash == 'some-thing-here') {
        // Your JS code here
        }
    });
```